# How to write an unlimited number in java as a double or at list as a decimal value

Tags: java, database, math, double

I have been seeking for an answer but couldn't found it...

I have a bank project and one of the demends are:
"platinum client can have unlimited credit limit".

In the DataBase i've written the value of platinumClientCommisionRate as varchar "unlimited"
But when i need to use it - in java action,
I dont know how to write  the method -"get_Platinum_Client_Rate()"

so.. How to write an unlimited number in java as a double or at list as a decimal value
somefriends told me to write '-1' but then how do i proceed with math calculation.

Thank you all

Comment: I really don't understand what you want. Are you trying to represent the concept of "unlimited" as a number?

Comment: When there is no limit, you can't do calculations with it.

Comment: Try with: double inf=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; But, representing money as double is a very very bad thing in Java!

Comment: **Side note**: consider using java naming conventions: `get_Platinum_Client_Rate()` should be named `getPlatinumClientRate()`

Comment: You need to treat "unlimited" rate as a special rate in your code. It doesn't matter how you store it in DB or what variable. All you need is treat it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

If there is no limit on Platinum Clients, why don't you just skip it in the calculation? Another thing is that if you ever deal with money use BigDecimals.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not know if `Integer` or `Double` are big enough for your numbers, use `BigDecimal`, which is (well theoretically not, but practically) unlimited regarding the range of numbers it can represent.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you would want a method like

```
getPlatinumClientRate()
```

if you already know it is unlimited?

Better approach IMHO:

```
Decimal limit = getClientRate(clientId);
if (limit == null) {
    // must be Platinum client, he has no limit
}
else {
    // ordinary client, tell them to go away or pay extraordinary interest rates.
}
```